# How to use smart-selects in Django admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to do smart-selects in Django admin panel using [django-smart-selects](https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I want to make sure that when creating a term, you first need to select an subject, and based on this item, select a section related to this subject.
I did `pip install django-smart-selects` and added `smart_selects` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Here is my code.

models.py

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Section(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    position = models.IntegerField()

class Term(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    section = ChainedForeignKey(Section, chained_field='subject', chained_model_field='subject', show_all=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    definition = models.TextField()
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('subjects.urls')),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I create a new term and choose a subject, I can select any section, not just related to this subject. I think I need to add `include('smart_selects.urls')` to the admin path.

I tried to do this, but it didn't change anything:

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('admin/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
```

Also I tried to do this, but it gives the "TypeError 'tuple' object is not a mapping":

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls, include('smart_selects.urls')),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in `admin.py` in the `TermAdmin` class, I wrote `autocomplete_fields = ['section']`. After removing this line, everything works.